# Is this a c++ compilation bug of the Visual Studio 2019? (Function parameter is passed incorrectly when optimization is turned ON)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

vs2019 Version 16.11.1

Function parameter is passed incorrectly when optimization is turned ON

Below is a minimal example code I’ve built to reproduce the problem:

1. The initial value of the member variable ‘x’ of ‘foo’ is 32.0f
2. Use the local variable ‘old’ in ‘inner_func’ to cache the ‘x’ value and pass it to the function ‘inner_print’ to print
3. It should output 32, but the actual output is 10 under release build (debug build is ok, and doesn’t have this issue)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    foo() {
        x = 32.0f;
        min_x = 4.0f;
    }

    void func(float val) {
        if (val < get_min_value()) {
            val = get_min_value();
        }

        inner_func(val);
    }

protected:
    void inner_func(float val) {
        float old = x;
        x = val;
        inner_print((int)old);
    }

    virtual float get_min_value() {
        return min_x;
    }

    void inner_print(int val) {
        cout << val << endl;
    }

private:
    float x;
    float min_x;
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.func(10.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

As @engf-010 suggested, I had reported this to Microsoft (use the feedback button in the right-upper corner of VS) using the redused-down version by @Bill Lynch:
[C++ compiler bug: incorrect output produced when optimization is turned ON (for vs2017, vs2019, vs2022)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-compiler-bug:-incorrect-output-produ/1683783)

And there is a report of a similar issue in the VS Developer Community:
[C++ compiler: Function parameter is passed incorrectly when optimization is turned ON](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-compiler-function-parameter-is-passed-incorrectl/1294254)

Comment: I reduced it down a bit to https://godbolt.org/z/7Pv9zxbdz. Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Yup,  `float should_be_32 = x_ + 0.f;` produces correct output.

Comment: Curious... This happens in VS 2017 also.  In the reduced example, either removing the `virtual` keyword or declaring one of the variables volatile (any one of `x_`, `val` or `should_be_32`) "fixes" it.

Comment: bizar this also works : float old = std::exchange( x ,val ) +0;

Comment: @SorXd : you should report this to Microsoft (use the feedback button in the right-upper corner of VS) ,may already be an known bug.

Comment: @engf-010 I have replied to a similar question in the vs Developer Community, not sure if it is the same problem... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-compiler-function-parameter-is-passed-incorrectl/1294254

Comment: @SorXD: Great ! Maybe you could add a link to this SO-question which has workarounds suggested.

Comment: Yes it is weird. Once I add `cout << "old " << old << endl;` in `inner_func`,it outputs fine.